# How to delay assignment of class values in Scala?

Tags: scala, oop

I have a class that gets created using data `a` read from a .conf file. The class also contains a value `b` which does not come from the conf file.

The class:

```
case class Configuration(a: String, b: String)
```

The sequence of calls to instantiate a Configuration looks like this:

User -> `ConfigurationCompiler` -> `ConfigurationReader` -> `readConfig(): Configuration`
(The user gets a Configuration object back)

Value `a` gets read and set by the .conf file, but value `b` is specified by the user. I don't want to pass value `b` all the way down to readConfig() so it can be set on instantiation of `Configuration`.

I have experimented with `Option`, but to me it looks ugly because you first instantiate `b` with `None`, and then set it later. Also, the tests look weird because you must test `Some(String)` instead of `String`. Option also doesn't seem like it fits here because the field is actually *not* optional, it is just set at a later time.

The `Option` class:

```
case class Configuration(a: String, var b: Option[String])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solution might be to use `implicit`, but `implicit String` doesn't look good - implicit types are resolved by type, so it should be something less general than `String`.

What I can think of is something like `PartialConfiguration` returned by `readConfig()`. Then you can add it's values to the values provided by `User` to create full `Configuration`.

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution that doesn't use defaults which I feel are not elegant if you intend to set them later. I like this approach because it gives back a complete object, that is explicitly stated as being a `PartialConfiguration`, instead of a `Configuration` with implied missing parts.

Comment: @jcallin Do you have to be able to inspect the `PartialConfiguration` objects? If not, you could just use a function `ConfInput => UserInput => Configuration` directly, without inventing any new classes to hold intermediate results. If you define `Configuration` in the simplest way possible as `case class Configuration(a: String, b: String)`, then the function `(confStr: String) => (userStr: String) => Configuration(confStr, userStr)` of type `String => String => Configuration` seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the original configuration object with a default value in the `b` position. When you get the actual value of `b`, then create a copy that is used by your program using:

```
val realConfig = originalConfig.copy( b = bValue )
```

The copy will have the field `b` replaced with the desired value for actual use.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a `builder`. Here's an example:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.ValidatedNel

case class ConfigBuilder(a: Option[String] = None, b: Option[String] = None) {
  def withA(a: String): ConfigBuilder = copy(a = Some(a))
  def withB(b: String): ConfigBuilder = copy(b = Some(b))
  def build: ValidatedNel[String, Configuration] =
    (a.toValidNel("'a' must be defined"), b.toValidNel("'b' must be defined"))
      .mapN(Configuration)
}
```

Validating both fields:

```
ConfigurationBuilder()
  .build
// Invalid(NonEmptyList('a' must be defined, 'b' must be defined))
```

Getting valid configuration:

```
ConfigurationBuilder()
  .withA("test")
  .withB("test2")
  .build
// Valid(Configuration(test,test2))
```